# Is there a way to block copy/paste from textview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextview, selection

i need a way to *deactivate the auto selection* from a **UITextView**.

[image]

I deselected all the attributes from interface builder, but when i touch the text, the selection appear!

Have a solution? A magick tricks?

thanks.

Comment: would `userInteractionEnabled = NO;` work for your purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a subclass of UITextView and override the canPerformAction method.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:)
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

The selector values you can expect from canPerformAction can be found in the [UIResponderStandardEditActions Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/UIResponderStandardEditActions)

The [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will help as well.

> **canPerformAction:withSender:**
>
> This default implementation of this
> method returns YES if the responder
> class implements the requested action
> and calls the next responder if it
> does not. Subclasses may override this
> method to enable menu commands based
> on the current state; for example, you
> would enable the Copy command if there
> is a selection or disable the Paste
> command if the pasteboard did not
> contain data with the correct
> pasteboard representation type. If no
> responder in the responder chain
> returns YES, the menu command is
> disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

So create a subclass of `UITextView` that overrides the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method and return 'NO' for every action that you don't want to perform on textview.